# how to get content of all <li> tags in one page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, html-lists

I have an html list something like this:

```
<li id="tag">red</li>
<li id="tag">yellow</li>
<li id="tag">blue</li>
```

How can I get the content of these li tags using jQuery?

For example;

```
$tags = red, yellow, blue
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MSFcz/)**

```
texts = $('li').map(function(){
  return $(this).text();
}).get().join(',');
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var $tags = $("li").map(function(){
  return $(this).text();
}).get().join(",");
```

Here, have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KTted/2/

Answer (score 3):

First, you should change your `id="tag"` to `class="tag"`, as you can't have multiple elements with the same id.

You can build an array of the values:

```
var content = [];
$("li").each(function (element) {
    content.push[$(element).text()];
});
```

Or as others have pointed out, you can use map:

```
var content = $("li").map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join(",");
```

Comment: map() return an object, not a string